# Change width of standard Lightning quick action lightbox

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

Standard Lightning Lead Convert lightbox has wider window than standard lightbox.

Is it possible to change it via standard settings?

Comment: Would be surprised if there is any such setting.

Comment: I think I have come across lightbox in the past, could you confirm if this is a specific custom component or in general you are looking for changing the width for any quick action screen?

Comment: @JayantDas yes, that if custom lightning component inside of lightbox.